# Javascript go to the next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, I'm sure there's some obvious answer to this, but I'll ask still.
So I have this project where the user is rolling dice, and writing what the dice is for and what is being done.
It works through html forms and the javascript prints the results without refreshing the page. I got all that working.
My current issue is that I want the result of the code to move on to the next line, and continue on when you click 'submit' again.

```
$( "#modTool" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());

    var a = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("user").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("actionTaken").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("target").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("amountOfDice").value;
    var sides = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("typeOfDice").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("bonus").value;

    var diceRoll = rollDice(amount, sides);

    var display=document.getElementById("Prompt");
    display.innerHTML = "&gt; " + a + " uses " + b + " towards " + c + "<br />" + "&gt; " + diceRoll + " Bonus " + d;
});
```

https://i.gyazo.com/fe3ffa835ed1acf41c08c7f6fe46ea93.png

It needs to both go to the next line, when I click 'submit' again, as well as having a scrollbar.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question. See this for further clarification.
https://jsfiddle.net/wckggf5g/

When you click submit again, it doesn't add another roll below.

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=` for innerHTML to concatenate

Comment: That did it! Thanks @kecalace !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line:

```
display.innerHTML += "&gt; " + a + " uses " + b + " towards " + c + "<br />" + "&gt; " + diceRoll + " Bonus " + d + "<br /><br />";
```

Instead of:

```
display.innerHTML = "&gt; " + a + " uses " + b + " towards " + c + "<br />" + "&gt; " + diceRoll + " Bonus " + d;
display.scrollTop = display.scrollHeight;
```

Add overflow to your `#Prompt` like this:

```
#Prompt {
    border-style: groove;
    height: 400px;
    max-width:98%;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**See working example:**

```js
function rollDie(sides) {
 if(!sides) sides = 6;
 with(Math) return 1 + floor(random() * sides);
}

function rollDice(number, sides) {
 var total = 0;
 while(number-- > 0) total += rollDie(sides);
 return total;
}

$( "#modTool" ).submit(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log($(this).serialize());

 var a = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("user").value;
 var b = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("actionTaken").value;
 var c = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("target").value;
 var amount = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("amountOfDice").value;
 var sides = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("typeOfDice").value;
 var d = document.getElementById("modTool").elements.namedItem("bonus").value;

 var diceRoll = rollDice(amount, sides);

 var display=document.getElementById("Prompt");
 display.innerHTML += "&gt; " + a + " uses " + b + " towards " + c + "<br />" + "&gt; " + diceRoll + " Bonus " + d + "<br /><br />";
  
 display.scrollTop = display.scrollHeight;
});
```

```css
* {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
#wrapper {
 max-width:98%;
 width:auto;
 margin:auto;
 background-color: #fff;
}
#Prompt {
 border-style: groove;
 height: 400px;
 max-width:98%;
 width:auto;
 position:relative;
        overflow-y: auto;
}
#Buttons {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
<div id="Prompt">
 <br />
<!-- <p id="diceRoll">
 </p>
-->

</div>
<br />
<div ="Buttons">
 <form id="modTool" method="POST" action="">
 <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <td><b>USER</b> </td>
   <td><select name="user" id="User">
   <option id="PC10">0</option>
   <option id="PC11">1</option>
   <option id="PC12">2</option>
   <option id="PC13">3</option>
   <option id="PC14">4</option>
   <option id="PC15">5</option>
   <option id="PC16">6</option>
   <option id="PC17">7</option>
   <option id="PC18">8</option>
   <option id="PC19">9</option>
   <option id="PC110">10</option>
   </select></td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <td><b>ACTION TAKEN</b> </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="actionTaken"></input>
  </td>
  <td>
   <td><b>TARGET</b> </td>
   <td><select name="target" id="target">
   <option id="PC20">0</option>
   <option id="PC21">1</option>
   <option id="PC22">2</option>
   <option id="PC23">3</option>
   <option id="PC24">4</option>
   <option id="PC25">5</option>
   <option id="PC26">6</option>
   <option id="PC27">7</option>
   <option id="PC28">8</option>
   <option id="PC29">9</option>
   <option id="PC210">10</option>
   </select></td>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <td><b>DICE SIDES</b> </td>
   <td><select name="typeOfDice" id="typeOfDice">
   <option id="D20">20</option>
   <option id="D100">100</option>
   </select></td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <td><b>AMOUNT OF DICE</b>
   <td><select name="amountOfDice" id="amountOfDice">
   <option id="1Dice">1</option>
   <option id="2Dice">2</option>
   <option id="3Dice">3</option>
   <option id="4Dice">4</option>
   <option id="5Dice">5</option>
   <option id="6Dice">6</option>
   <option id="7Dice">7</option>
   <option id="8Dice">8</option>
   <option id="9Dice">9</option>
   <option id="10Dice">10</option>
   </select></td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <td><b>BONUS</b> </td>
   <td><select name="bonus" id="bonus">
   <option id="plus0">0</option>
   <option id="plus1">+1</option>
   <option id="plus2">+2</option>
   <option id="plus3">+3</option>
   <option id="plus4">+4</option>
   <option id="plus5">+5</option>
   <option id="plus6">+6</option>
   <option id="plus7">+7</option>
   <option id="plus8">+8</option>
   <option id="plus9">+9</option>
   <option id="plus10">+10</option>
   <option id="Minus1">-1</option>
   <option id="Minus2">-2</option>
   <option id="Minus3">-3</option>
   <option id="Minus4">-4</option>
   <option id="Minus5">-5</option>
   <option id="Minus6">-6</option>
   <option id="Minus7">-7</option>
   <option id="Minus8">-8</option>
   <option id="Minus9">-9</option>
   <option id="Minus10">-10</option>
   </select></td>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="submit" name="submitRound" id="submit"></input>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
</div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Added overflow and made it autoscroll to bottom.

Comment: Thanks @sjaakvbrabant ! That did it! Appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, if you have questions let me know!